# Match array to table row index, do actions for each

Tags: jquery, arrays, cookies

I have a table like the below example.

```
<tr>
    <td>Content #1a</td>
    <td>Content #1b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Content #2a</td>
    <td>Content #2b</td>
</tr>
```

And an Array value with the same number of values as there are table rows.

```
var arr = [ 0, 0 ]
```

Currently I have them linked so when a row is clicked on it will hide/show the row, update the corresponding array value, then save the array as a cookie.

```
var $tr = $('tbody tr').on('click', function () {
    var i = $tr.index(this);
        if(arr[i] == 0) {
        arr[i] = 1;
        // hide it
        }
        else {
        arr[i] = 0;
        // show it
        }
    $.cookie("CName", arr, { expires: 1, path: '/'});
});
```

The problem is I dont know how to do that in reverse, so convert cookie to array, then show/hide the corresponding row based on the array value.

```
var arr = $.cookie("CName").split(',');
```

The idea is to have it remember which rows the user had hidden on page load.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $.each(arr,function(index,el){
        var tr = $('tbody:nth-child('+index+')');
        if(el == 1)
           $(tr).show();
        else
           $(tr).hide();
    });
```

> This seems to hide every second TR regardless of whats set in the
>   array.

the problem is that nth-child starts from 1 change that line to

```
 var tr = $('tbody tr:eq(' + index + ')');
```

this will fix it.

Comment: This seems to hide every second TR regardless of whats set in the array.